# OAuth is limited to 100 sensitive scope logins until OAuth consent screen is published

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-cloud

я попыталась создать айди клиента мне выскочила такая ошибка что нужна публикация для создания

[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9cTj.png)

я опубликовал окно входа но это не помогло
[published window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buvfd.png)

ошибка также появляется

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54hj5.png)

пожалуйста подскажите что можно сделать чтоб создать oauth client ID,спасибо

Answer (score 0):

> OAuth is limited to 100 sensitive scope logins until OAuth consent screen is published

Через время после публикации приветственного экрана все должно придти в норму.